# dynamic working of react native circular slider

Tags: reactjs, native

I am using react native circular slider but it functional well only for Max value 360.When i set dynamic value for max it stucks at that number while i want a full rotation depemding on that number not 360.Can anybody help me out with this.

Comment: Please update your question and post your code as well, without knowing what is going on in your code it is nearly not possible to assist you for anyone :)

Comment: actually i m using react-native-circle-slider library.It has 360 value by default as max and when i set my max value 33 it stops slider indicator at 33 .I want it to fully rotate and form circle for any dynamic value i want.